# Disabling data limit notifications for disabled SIM?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, mobile-data, data-monitoring, dual-sim

I have a Motorola G (2nd gen) with dual SIM. Only one SIM at a time can be used for mobile data. I have limited free data on both SIMs. When the first SIM reaches this limit, I switch mobile data over to the second SIM. Everything works as expected, except that the notification about the data limit being reached on the first SIM does not disappear.

How do I disable data limit notifications for the SIM where mobile data is disabled?

I can work around the problem by temporarily setting the limit too high for the disabled SIM and resetting them to the correct amount when I next activate it, but this is inconvenient. It is counterintuitive for a disable SIM to show data notifications.

Comment: Is it a sticky notification or can it be swiped? For latter, you can automatically have it swiped through MacroDroid app. For former, and provided the device is rooted and has xposed framework installed, the app NotifyClean should work.

Comment: @Firelord It is sticky. I guess NotifyClean couldn't discern between notifications from active SIM (wanted) and disabled SIM (unwanted). Anyway, if there really is no way to handle this without additional apps, I will stick to my manual workaround. It seemed a pretty obvious problem, so I assumed it was a problem of me not knowing how to configure something and not android actually not being able to handle this scenario. I am still hoping.